# Zero Motorcycle - Remove Battery for winter?

Tags: motorcycle, battery, electric-vehicle

I consider buying myself an electric Motorcycle. I really like the model Zero S and also the DS version. My Question now is, since I read that cold temperature isnt that good for the Battery over a longer time, if it is possible to remove it for the Winter and Store it inside since can't just take a motorbike inside my house.. 
Someone has experience with that ?

Thanks in advance
CN

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want the Zero FX and Zero FXS, which have hot swappable battery modules, batteries can be removed and installed in under 1 minute.

[Source at bottom of this page](http://www.zeromotorcycles.com/technology/)